# How do I learn and use optaplanner ? any detailed tutorials/videos available online apart from the ones in optaplanner website?

Tags: java

I have a beginners level knowledge in Java , I am trying to learn optaplanner , can anyone help me finding the right resources to learn optaplanner and spring/springboot integration ,since my background is operations research I am new to spring environment.

Comment: Would you see this [link](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/video.html) or [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/4835/199)? there are useful answers to this in the OR.SE forum that you can search. :)

Answer (score 2):

These should help:

1. In the [OptaPlanner documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/documentation.html), section 2.4 is a specific **Quick Start guide for Spring Boot**. But if you're new to Spring, why not learn [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) instead, which is faster and supports native compilation?
2. The [optaplanner-quickstarts](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts) repository has [one Spring Boot example](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/java-spring-boot) and [several Quarkus examples](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases). Just git clone that repo or [download it](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/archive/refs/heads/stable.zip).

Comment: Note: [OptaPlanner continues as Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork)